# Error while copying the model from a mac to a windows pc

Tags: anylogic

I would like to use my model at another laptop. Currently I use a macbook. After I try to use my copied model on a windows laptop it says: `Illegal char at index 21` and it linked to my databases. Somebody who had the same problem? I copied the complete folder so I dont know why it cant detect my databases.

Comment: this is probably provoked by an incorrect path... directory paths to files are different in windows and mac, so check that out

Comment: Agree with Felipe. And the illegal char will likely be a file-separator "\" which is different on both systems...

Comment: How can I delete import databases: input data sources where the path is outside of the model? I can't click the delete button. the path is grey and I cant do anything